# How do you get a single column of a gridview to auto-update without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a gridview with multiple columns, but only one of the columns should dynamically change. Each row has a "status" value that I require a database call to update.  I have written a function to do that call, but the current approach I've written to update it refreshes the entire page.  This is obtrusive, since refreshing removes state (selected values in other areas of the page, scrolled location, etc).

Here is the code I've written to try to set this up:

```
<div class = "my_gridview">
    <asp:Timer ID = "timer_1" OnTick = "timer_1Tick" runat = "server" Interval = "25" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID = "update_panel" UpdateMode = "Conditional" runat = "server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "timer_1" EventName = "Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="my_gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
                GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" 
                CssClass="table table-bordered x-condensed cameraDetails" OnRowDataBound = "my_list_RowDataBound"
                EmptyDataText = "There are no generated heatmaps">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField meta:resourceKey = "StringSourceID">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID = "srcTitleLbl" runat="server" Text = "Source" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID = "srcLbl" runat="server" CssClass="LinkBtn_Type" meta:resourceKey="srcLblResource" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField meta:resourceKey = "StringStatus">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID = "statusTitleLbl" runat="server" Text = "Status" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID = "statusLbl" runat="server" CssClass="LinkBtn_Type" meta:resourceKey="statusLblResource" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

How can this be done where it doesn't refresh the entire page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UpdatePanels do a partial postback, but that still goes through the page lifecycle, which causes the removal of state. You can investigate persisting things like item selection (checkboxes, rows, etc.), but you will most likely spend a lot of time creating this and maintaining it will be a nightmare.

To truly avoid the page lifecycle and achieve the user experience you are describing, then use a client-side solution, like plain JavaScript, KnockoutJS, Backbone or AngularJS. These approaches will leave your page state alone while sending/retrieving data to the server and then, potentially, update portions of the page.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm surprised with all of ASP.NET's ajax functions that it can't handle partial page updates.  I'm looking for a C# function to be run at some regular interval (thus the timer), and then to update the value in the gridview based on the new resulting value.  This is exclusively possible with extra external javascript functionality?

Comment: @Jim - not exclusively possible, but you will spend a lot of time maintaining the state of the page for all user interaction you wish to monitor that you most likely want to abandon the notion and certainly someone coming after you looking at your code will probably want your home address to "speak" with you about the code.

Client-side solutions like KnockoutJS allow for a view model to be synchronized (two-way binding) with the DOM, thus if you change the UI by action, then the view model would be updated and vice-versa if update the view model then the DOM elements can be updated.

Comment: @Jim - you can use KnockoutJS on one page and not the rest of your web application if you wish.  I generally have a shell .aspx page to leverage the security features of ASP.NET and then use KnockoutJS to handle the client-side, I either use ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, web services or ASP.NET Web API on the server-side and use jQuery to create AJAX calls to the server-side pieces.

Comment: @Jim - To answer your original question about you being surprised that ASP.NET AJAX cannot handle a true partial page update, you have to realize that UpdatePanels were designed to be a poor man's AJAX that wrap around existing ASP.NET server controls. The ASP.NET page life-cycle lives on underneath the covers. UpdatePanels provide a quick way to enhance your ASP.NET server controls and provide a more seamless user experience, but they come at a cost of being difficult to work with when you do anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: A bit disappointing!  I was sure that this kind of functionality would be requested often enough that they would work around the page life cycle, or provide some javascript wrappers for it.  In any case, thanks for the detailed response.  It is much appreciated!

Comment: @Jim - Microsoft has abandoned the ASP.NET AJAX library and officially endorsed jQuery, they even have contributed to some of the core jQuery features (such as templating). ASP.NET MVC is Microsoft's server solution that avoids the page lifecycle and server controls. The ASP.NET Page Lifecycle was and still is, in certain usage, a very viable option, hence the reason Microsoft continues to update the ASP.NET WebForms framework. With the rise of client-side functionality though, it is the user experience that is driving developers towards alternatives to WebForms.